# User defined struct does not recognized and gives type error when declaring

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct

```
#include <iostream>
#pragma once

using namespace std;

struct Process
{
    string name;
    int arrival_time;
    int deadline;
    int task_count;
    int priority;
    Stack task_stack;
    Process *next;
};
struct Subtask
{
    string name;
    int duration;
    Subtask *next;
};
struct Stack
{
    Subtask *head;
    void init();
    void close();
    void push(Subtask *in);
    Subtask *pop();
    bool isEmpty();
};
```

This file is one of my source files. When i try to compile code i get "‘Stack’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘obstack’?".

Comment: [Please do not post images of code because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Code should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: It is because `Stack` is not declared before being used. The declaration of `Stack` (and `Subtask` that is used from `Stack`) should be before the declaration of `Process` (that uses `Stack`).

Answer (score 1):

It is because Stack is not declared before being used. The declaration of `Stack` (and `Subtask`, which is used from `Stack`) should be before the declaration of `Process` (that uses `Stack`).

```
#include <iostream>
#pragma once

using namespace std;

struct Subtask
{
    string name;
    int duration;
    Subtask *next;
};
struct Stack
{
    Subtask *head;
    void init();
    void close();
    void push(Subtask *in);
    Subtask *pop();
    bool isEmpty();
};
struct Process
{
    string name;
    int arrival_time;
    int deadline;
    int task_count;
    int priority;
    Stack task_stack;
    Process *next;
};
```